# Deleting Docker Images from Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

We are doing an artifactory cleanup, removing Docker images from our docker repo.
I understand from the article over https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-delete-docker-images-older-than-a-certain-time-period

that if a layer is shared between two different images, and if only one is a candidate for deletion, **then that layer will not be deleted from the binary storage**.

Our policy is on deleting some specific tag versions (that are not used in production) and now we have some queries based on the above article

1. Is there a possibility that we will end up with partially deleted images (corrupted images). Say some of the layers of the image we are trying to delete is referenced by some other image, would layers be partially deleted, leaving us with a corrupted image **which could be be pulled, but then result in failure?**?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, if the layer is referenced by another tag, then it will not be deleted.
The worst that can happen is that you will leave a tag behind that points to a non-existent image.

Comment: Thanks @Constantin. And it should be recoverable by pushing the image again, am I correct?

Comment: You can push the entire image again and will get a new layer that you can use for the tag